Formatting Validation Errors in ValidatorConstraint
I have this validators which validates an array of value ids. as follows:
@Injectable()
@ValidatorConstraint({ async: true })
export class CustomValidator implements ValidatorConstraintInterface {
  public constructor(
    // to fetch the required fields
    private readonly fieldsService: fieldsService,
    // to fetch the provided values
    private readonly valuesService: valuesService,
  ) {}

  public async validate(
    valuesIds: string[],
    validationArguments: ValidationArguments,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    // first fetch the required fields
    const requiredFields = await this.fieldsService.findRequired();

    const fetches: Array<Promise<Values[]>> = []

    for (let i = 0; i < valuesIds.length; i += 1) {
      fetches.push(this.valuesService.findById(valuesIds[i]));
    }

    const values = Promise.all(fetches);

    for (let i = 0; i < requiredFields.length; i += 1) {
      // find the value with the corresponding field Id
      const value = values.find(v => v.fieldId === requiredFields[i].id);

      if (!value) {
        // this is the issue I want to validate all fields instead of just one
       // and I want to it to be formatted in the following fashion
      // { fieldId: "corresponding error" }
        throw new Error(`${requiredField.name} is required`);
      }
    
    return true;
  }
}

I could return false from the validate function but the problem is it will only be one message for one field and it will be assigned to the values field intead of the fieldId.
